# Angular typescript dropdown not selecting default value

Tags: html, angular, select

I was having some problem when trying to set the default selected value for dropdown using Angular typescript. 
Here is my code in html:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <strong><label class="form-control-label" 
                jhiTranslate="staff.department" 
                for="field_department">Department</label></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control" id="field_department" 
                name="department" [(ngModel)]="staff.department">
                    <option [ngValue]="null" selected disabled>
                     Please select an Option</option>
                    <option [ngValue]="departmentOption.id === staff.department?.id ? 
                    staff.department : departmentOption" 
                 *ngFor="let departmentOption of departments | orderBy: 'departmentName'">
                   {{departmentOption.departmentName}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I launch the page, by default, the dropdown option for `"Please select an Option"` supposed to show in the dropdown, however, in my case, it is empty. Any idea why is it so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting `staff.department=null` initially

**in ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.staff.department=null
}
```

**in html**

```
<select class="form-control" id="field_department" name="department" [(ngModel)]="staff.department">
     <option [ngValue]=null disabled>Please select an Option</option>
        //rest code
</select>
```

Comment: using ngInit in <select> or?

Comment: yea in ngOnInit. Also remove selected from  <option [ngValue]="null" selected disabled>Please select an Option</option>

Comment: But then I want that one to be show as default upon page launch

Comment: If you set staff.department as null initially then when it loads your null option will be set automatically

Comment: Can I check with you let's say I set it to '' in this case will work also?

Comment: if you set this.staff.department='' you should set ngValue to '', i.e. <option [ngValue]='' disabled>Please select an Option</option>

Comment: I tried to set this for another dropdown using '' but it does not work though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190809/discussion-between-seba-cherian-and-hyperfkcb).

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `"anyvariable that is not defined in typescript"` as default value to option

```
<select class="form-control" id="field_department" name="department"
 [(ngModel)]="staff.department">
             <option [ngValue]="anythingNotDefinedYet" selected disabled>
             Please select an Option</option>
             <option [ngValue]="departmentOption.id === 
             staff.department?.id ? staff.department : departmentOption" 
             *ngFor="let departmentOption of departments | orderBy: 'departmentName'">
             {{departmentOption.departmentName}}</option>
  </select>
```

**[Stackblitz Demo showing the case](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-tvgky2?file=app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

try `<option [ngValue]="undefined" selected disabled>Please select an Option</option>`